# importing all assets into one images.js file then export as one object

Tags: reactjs, webpack

in my react app, currently, in each component I import an image/icon or simply:
`const someIcon = '../../images/icon_car.png'`
and then use it.
I tried to concentrate all assets into one images.js file which is currently in the same folder as /assets.
However whenever I try to use the asset in another file I get a 'file not found error'. and apparently the URL becomes '/fonts/' (because of webpack targeting all images into that folder apparently).

```
so I've got images.js which is something like that:

import carIcon from './icon_car.png';
import manIcon from './icon_man.png';

const IMAGES = {
  carIcon,
  manIcon,
};

export default IMAGES;
// and in myComponent.jsx:
import IMAGES from '../../assets/images';
.
.
.
and then <img src={IMAGES.carIcon} /> for example for accessing the icon.
```

whenever I try to access the imported Icon from another component I get file not found in the console.

my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
    ],
  },
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': ['./js/app.js'].concat(glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js')),

  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|png|gif)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/',
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
  ],
});
```

UPDATE:

I just noticed another strange/alarming behaviour in my project:
when I go inside my myComponent.jsx and import my asset:
`import { vehicleIcon } from'../../../static/images/icon_car.png';`
the vehicleIcon is not shown in screen when I try to render it !!!
also: console.log(vehicleIcon) ==> undefined !

ANOTHER UPDATE:
another thing I noticed:
whenever I use in any component in my app: 
it works. but also in  and I can keep ../../../../images as long as I wish and the asset is still recognized and painted on screen.
but when I import someIcon from '../../path_to_assets..', then someIcon is undefined ! (even though my linter approved it is the correct folder)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
const IMAGES = {
  carIcon:'icon_car.png',
  manIcon:'icon_man.png',
};

export default IMAGES;
```

// and in myComponent.jsx:

```
import IMAGES from '../../assets/images';
//Usage
<img src={"path to image folder/"+IMAGES.carIcon} />
```

Comment: but if I understand correctly what you suggest is that IMAGES.carIcon will be the string './icon_car.png' which is not the relative pass from myComponent.jsx folder to the asset and therefore will not work. I will try it and report if it works.

Comment: yes ofcourse it did not work. the path './icon_car.png' is not recognized by the component simply because icon_car.png is not in the component folder ! but thank you anyway

Comment: but that does not solve my problem - which is how NOT to deal with the relative path from the component to the assets folder. my goal is to simply: <img src={IMAGES.carIcon} />